# how to put tabulator as parameter for sudo in sudoers file

Tags: sudo, shell-scripting

I would like to give for specific user allowing to put tabulator as parameter to program.
Full invoking looks like:

```
sudo /sbin/vgs --units b --nosuffix --noheadings --separator 'TAB'
```

I try to put it like:

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/vgs --units b --nosuffix --noheading --separator 'TAB'
```

(TAB is of course tabulator character).
Unfortunly - it doesn't work - sudo ask for password and doesn't recognize command. When i ommit 'TAB' section - it works fine. Problem is both with TAB character, and with '.
How to avoid it and allow puting tabulator as parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I propose to put the command into a shell script and just give sudo rights for this script. Just make sure the users aren't allowed to edit it.

Comment: it's good workaround - but - only workaround ;)